# how to recover the (context) information of the original selected records before executing the wizard?

Tags: forms, python-2.7, odoo, wizard

I'm using OpenERP web 6.1.

- step1: I have form 1 - button 1 opening form2.
- step2: From form 2 button 2 is opening form 3.
- step3: from form 3 (where users are selecting some values) I return to form 2 using the values selected in form 3.

The issue is how can i use the initial context that I had on step2 (i need id and values from form 1).

In step 3 I'm using the context['active_ids'] but when returning to form2 I'm not able to find form1 id in context.

Related is the following but I don't know how to do it:

https://answers.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+question/116262

Answer (score 1):

I got it working!

Form 2 xml file in declaring action i have the context:

```
<field name="context">{'res_id': active_ids}</field>
```

And in form 3 .py file i have:

```
context.update({'res1_id': context['active_ids']})
```

Now in the py file of form 2 wizard i'm able to use:

```
context['res_id']
```

to get the id of form 1.

Many thanks!